# Looking for C# generics/delegate katas

Tags: c#-4.0

Any recommendations for katas covering generics and delegates in C#?

Most of the member on my team can code generics and delegates, but always require a quick look at the documentation or an example to jump start our brains on them.  So I thought that for our daily kata we would cover these aspects for a couple of weeks until we can read and write them by instinct.

This would make it easier for us to use these tools in our coding retreats for design patterns.

Thanks in advance for any recommendations...

Answer (score 4):

You may think this terribly vain of me to suggest, but how about doing the same sort of exercise as I've been engaging in for the last month or so? Namely [reimplementing LINQ to Objects](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/category/Edulinq). My posts aren't in kata form, but you might find them useful to suggest an ordering, and they could give you hints if you get stuck.

LINQ to Objects is all about delegates and is based on generic sequences (with plenty of generic methods involved) so between the tests and the implementation you'll get a lot of practice in - and get to know LINQ better at the same time!

If you're only doing it for a specific exercise you could always ignore some of the trickier operators (like OrderBy etc).

Comment: Awesome resource, thanks for sharing your exercises.  I only had time to browse a couple of them today, but I could easily turn any of the ones I looked at into a kata.

Comment: I found two links on Codeplex - currently developers are putting new stuffs weekly basis. I am expecting some good kata stuffs in future :
http://katas.codeplex.com/ and 
http://tddkatas.codeplex.com/

Comment: @JonSkeet your link looks like it is broken, could you update it please?

Comment: @TheLukeMcCarthy: Fixed, thanks.